# Hadith about the prophet and his daughter fatimah tongue suckling

Tags: hadith, prophet-muhammad, hadith-interpretation, fatima-zahra

Musnad of Ibn Hanbal: "Muhammad would not sleep until he sucked the tongue of his daughter Fatima and nuzzled his face in her bosom."
I want to know if this hadith is authentic or not(fabrication) and if it is authentic I want to know the purpose/reason to why the prophet muhammed(peace and blessings be upon him) did this

Comment: There is no such hadith, not sure where you got that from. Above duplicate is closet to your concern.

Comment: i have read that duplicate before posting the question and it did relax me a little bit but im still thinking about this hadith i got it from a muslim asking about it and it intrigued me 
are you sure that is a fabrication?

Comment: The hadith doesn't exist in Musnad of ibn Hanbal.  So yes it's a fabrication and one of those things that pops up on the internet.

Answer (score 2):

According to the few inormation (No Hadith Number, No Narrtor quoted) i tried to find any support for this "Hadith", what i could say after a certain search:

Well there's no such hadith as far as i can say after a certain research. The only version which seem near to this which is in Musnad al-Imam Ahmad is the Version which says that our Messenger sucked the Tongue of his grand son's narrated by Mu'awiya ibn abi Sufyan (which is quoted in the possible duplicate post).

And the Addition "sucked her tongue" in the Hadith in Sunan [abi Dawod](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/14/74) is qualified to be da'if but it's not quoting Fatima (May Allah be pleased with her) at all.

A Version excluding many "bad things" could be find in [Sunan abi Dawod](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/43/445) or [al-Adab-Al Mufrad](http://sunnah.com/adab/42) from Imam al Bukhari or [Sunan at-Timridi](http://sunnah.com/urn/737600) all narrated by Aisha.

It seems that a shi'a Version from bihar al-Anwar بحار الأنوار from al-Majalisi is not far from that one you quoted and a strange addition could be find in  فيض القدير في شرح الجامع الصغير Fayd al-Qadir from al-Manawi which seem also near to the quoted hadith and pretends that the Addition "he sucked the tongue" was quoted in Sunan abi Dawod, but the only Hadith which quotes this is the one which i refer to above! And al-Manawi didn't quote a source for the rest of this narration so either he mistaken or mixed between different Narrations: therefore this can't be qualified to be sahih!

But as a **conclusion**:
I only could find the Hadith you mentioned on websites against Islam pretending either it comes from Musnad Ahmad ibn Hanbal without any other Information (like Narrator, Hadith#) or from some Shia'a books. The only muslim version could only be found in a commentary of a scholar (al-Manawi) without any background or reference, where he also pretends that the addition "he sucked the tongue" is in Sunan abi Dawod, as i could proof this addition is a reason for many scholars to consider the Hadith -which is not quoting Fatima (May Allah be pleased with her) at all- to be weak!

This hadith or better narration isn't from Musnad al-Imam Ahamd ibn Hanbal! No part of it could be found in any sahih book therefore this hadith or narration (must have/ or) has been fabricated

And Allah knows best!